# Уведомление которое нельзя убрать

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-notification

Всем привет. Допустим создаю уведомление обычное в сервисе с помощью NotificationCompat.Builder. Это уведомления должно стоять все время и не уходить в бок пока работает сервис. Как сделать Уведомление которое не уходит в бок?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы сделать неудаляемое уведомление, вам нужно в вашем builder указать атрибут:

**`setOngoing (true);`**

вот например как все будет выглядеть целиком:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_launcher)

                        .setContentTitle("My title")

                        .setOngoing(true)  

                        .setContentText("Small text with details");
```

[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795336/android-notification-swipe-delete-disabling) на первоисточник.

Answer (score 1):

Если нотификация привязана к работе сервиса, то посмотрите в сторону [foreground сервисов](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=ru#Foreground). Вкратце, метод сервиса `startForeground` принимает нотификацию, которую невозможно будет смахнуть (даже `setOngoing(true)` ставить необязательно) и которая отображается всё время, пока не будет вызван метод `stopForeground`. Само по себе использование foreground сервиса гарантирует, что он не будет завершён системой, даже если приложение свёрнуто, даже на Android 8.

Comment: Круто обязательно почитаю про это